# How can I display and manipulate durations in Altair charts using Pandas data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization, altair

Does anyone know how can I work with time (as duration - not hours of a day) in **altair charts**?

I have a Pandas dataset which each line represents a flight. There are two columns, the first one with a column of `string` with the name of a person, the other column of `Pandas.Timedelta` type which represents the duration of the flight. I would like to show this information in altair chart grouped by person in the 'X axis' and accumulated flight hours in the 'Y' axis with hh:mm:ss format.

This is my dataset and what I tried to do.

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import streamlit as st

data = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['MARCOS', 'JOE', 'MICHAEL', 'MARCOS', 'MICHAEL', 'MARCOS', 'MARCOS'],
                     'Flight hours': [pd.Timedelta(50, 'hours'),
                                      pd.Timedelta(30, 'hours'),
                                      pd.Timedelta(20, 'hours'),
                                      pd.Timedelta(10, 'hours'),
                                      pd.Timedelta(70, 'hours'),
                                      pd.Timedelta(20, 'hours'),
                                      pd.Timedelta(10, 'hours')]})

data_grouped = pd.groupby(data)[['Fligh hours']].sum()


chart = alt.Chart(data_grouped).mark_bar().encode()
st.altair_chart(chart)
```

I'm getting this ERROR.

```
Error: Unrecognized type: "Duration" (18)
```

This is the result I want

[Link to the graphic sample desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkDpp.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a sample data set and what you have tried in Altair as well as the behavior your are expecting to see?

Comment: Of course! I'll do that right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is beneficial to troubleshoot outside of streamlit; in this case you would get an error message pointing you in the right direction if you use altair directly. You could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['MARCOS', 'JOE', 'MICHAEL', 'MARCOS', 'MICHAEL', 'MARCOS', 'MARCOS'],
    'Flight hours': [
        pd.Timedelta(50, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(30, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(20, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(10, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(70, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(20, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(10, 'hours')
    ]
})
data['Flight hours'] = data['Flight hours'].dt.total_seconds() // 3600

alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Name',
    y='sum(Flight hours)'
)
```

[image]

I couldn't get it to work with the hh:mm:ss output, there is a suggestions in this thread https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/967#issuecomment-399774414, but I don't know how to get rid of the `days`, so this is the closest I get:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['MARCOS', 'JOE', 'MICHAEL', 'MARCOS', 'MICHAEL', 'MARCOS', 'MARCOS'],
    'Flight hours': [
        pd.Timedelta(50, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(30, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(20, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(10, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(70, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(20, 'hours'),
        pd.Timedelta(10, 'hours')
    ]
}).groupby('Name', as_index=False)[['Flight hours']].sum()

data['Flight hours'] = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01') + data['Flight hours']

alt.Chart(data).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Name',
    y='hoursminutesseconds(Flight hours)'
)
```

[image]